# transform a sqaure shape drawable in to circular shape drawable withaout affecting the pixel quality

Tags: android, android-camera, android-canvas, android-drawable, android-capture

I have an application which takes picture from camera .And normally this pictures have either rectangle shapes or square shapes.But due to make these pictures circular in shape i limited the shape to only square.So now my problem is to make this square picture into a circular shape having radius of half of  width or height.And the clipped part should be removed from the picture.

Its same like making a circle from the square which touches midpoint of all of the faces of square.
I don't have any experience with canvas or other in built drawing functions.

[image]

For example i have square at first now i want to make image circular such that parts pointed by arrow should get clipped from image.

Note:as i have to work with camera images .quality is crucial factor.So please suggest the possible ways that will not affect the pixel quality and other important  factors.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by masking the image with your desired shape, see [this post](https://plus.google.com/113818537733281601685/posts/dUsQbRPohs6) for detailed info. 
example code:

```
Resources resources = context.getResources();
Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,R.drawable.original);
Bitmap mask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,R.drawable.mask);
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(mask.getWidth(), mask.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(result);
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
c.drawBitmap(original, 0, 0, null);
c.drawBitmap(mask, 0, 0, paint);
paint.setXfermode(null);
imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
```

Comment: what is R.drawable.mask here.Is it a hollow ring or just another drawable having circluar shape.Can you specify some details.
And ya thnx for sharing the code sample.:)

Comment: in this sample it's a circular shape, but it would be better if you drawn it yourself in dimensions of the captured image from camera (e.g. 1600x1200)